# get Laravel app_key remotely

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel framework. And to increase security,
I want to read app_key from a remote host instead of saving it directly to the .env file. and save it to the variable, then use it without Laravel having a problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you think this would increase security? Consider posting a question on [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) asking whether this will actually increase security. Not wanting to save a key in a file is a reasonable measure, but one would usually save it in the environment variables (not file), which would provide the same level of security as a remote host, but with less hassle.

Comment: I use Encrypt helper to store some data encrypted in the database.
If the server is hacked and the hacker has access to the files, it can easily decrypt the data stored in the database using app_key in .env.
But if the app_key is read remotely, the hacker's job will be difficult.

Comment: If they have access they can just read the key?

Comment: @hcwb are you sure it will be more difficult in that case, and not just more annoying? If the server is compromised, the attacker can just make a request to the other server to get the `app_key`. Your `app_key` server will have no way to distinguish an attacker's request from the server's. This is called Breach of Trust. I would argue that it is more annoying but not more secure, and security by annoyance is really not any security at all. Focus on making your system more secure using techniques that will genuinely help.

Comment: Sensitive data is stored encrypted in the database, and everyone needs a key to read it.
Normally, hackers download the database when they have access and read app_key from .env.
But if this key is read remotely, the hacker must first read the source code and debug to get the key. And that's something they don't expect, and it's time consuming.
I'm not saying this completely provides security, but I think it can improve security, and maybe at least it's better than storing it as clear text in a file.